# Javascript iframe set src on load

Tags: javascript, iframe, src, same-origin-policy

I have an iframe which is displaying using the src attribute, this works fine, when webpage loads inside iframe I have a load listener so I can tell when the iframe website is loading a new page due to user clicking inside the iframe, however the src attribute never changes from the original even though I can look at the iframe window location href value and see it is different.  I would love to be able to use frame.src = window.location.href but it won't allow me to do so due to Same Origin Policy, I would have thought that inside the iframe you could do what you want, I'm not attempting to update anything in the parent, I just want the iframe src attribute to hold the correct src, the reason I want this is that a user could click on another page in the parent then decide to click back to the page which has the iframe inside it, when they do this currently it will load to original src and not where the website the user was on.

I think what I'm looking for should be possible or is it?

Comment: If the iframe is not in your domain, you can not access where the iframe is.

Comment: I create the iframe and for example set the src: 'http://aa.com' when creating the iframe, the user then clicks on a contact button inside iframe but checking the iframe src it still show 'http://aa.com' instead of somethign like 'http://aa.com/contact' I can access the iframes window.location and see that the href is indeed 'http:aa.com/contact', I just want to set the iframe src so that it matches the href.  I'm not interacting with the parent window or anything like that, for clarification my parent could be 'http://bb.com'

Comment: You can not do anything unless you have control over both domains.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that I can't keep track of what webpage the iframe is on so that if a user navigates away via the parent then back again to the page containing the iframe, that I can't have the iframe show the last page it was on rather than load the default src I specified in the iframe when it was first called

Comment: Well the Same Origin Policy prevents you from doing it. If it were in the same domain, you would have no issues reading the location of the page.

Comment: what, if any, options do I have?  Ask the other domain to allow access?